# How to import C libraries in a Zig program?

Tags: zig

I'm trying to run this simple `main.zig` file with `zig run main.zig` that relies on a shared library [libsecp256k1](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1):

```js
const c = @cImport(@cInclude("secp256k1.h"));
const std = @import("std");

const FLAGS_TYPE_CONTEXT = 1 << 0;
const FLAGS_BIT_CONTEXT_SIGN = 1 << 9;
const FLAGS_TYPE_COMPRESSION = 1 << 1;
const FLAGS_BIT_COMPRESSION = 1 << 8;
const CONTEXT_SIGN = (FLAGS_TYPE_CONTEXT | FLAGS_BIT_CONTEXT_SIGN);
const EC_COMPRESSED = (FLAGS_TYPE_COMPRESSION | FLAGS_BIT_COMPRESSION);

pub fn main() !void {
    var sk: [32]u8 = undefined;

    var c_pk: c.secp256k1_pubkey = undefined;
    var ctx = c.secp256k1_context_create(CONTEXT_SIGN);
    if (c.secp256k1_ec_pubkey_create(ctx, &c_pk, &sk) == 0) {
        std.debug.print("error creating pubkey\n", .{});
        return;
    }

    var size: usize = 33;
    var pk: [33]u8 = undefined;
    if (c.secp256k1_ec_pubkey_serialize(ctx, &pk, &size, &c_pk, EC_COMPRESSED) == 0) {
        std.debug.print("error serializing pubkey\n", .{});
        return;
    }
    std.debug.print("public key ({d}): {s}\n", .{ size, std.fmt.fmtSliceHexLower(&pk) });
}
```

But Zig is unable to find the dependency and fails with:

```
main.zig:1:11: error: C import failed
const c = @cImport(@cInclude("secp256k1.h"));
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.zig:1:11: note: libc headers not available; compilation does not link against libc
referenced by:
    main: main.zig:14:15
    callMain: /usr/lib/zig/std/start.zig:574:32
    remaining reference traces hidden; use '-freference-trace' to see all reference traces
/home/fiatjaf/.cache/zig/o/47ca5f5e5b1a72513af35a101803ad7d/cimport.h:1:10: error: 'secp256k1.h' file not found
#include <secp256k1.h>
```

It's not clear from any piece of information I can find *where* is Zig going to search for these libraries.

For example, if I change the first line to the full path to the shared headers

```js
const c = @cImport(@cInclude("/usr/local/include/secp256k1.h"));
```

then I get a different error:

```
error: ld.lld: undefined symbol: secp256k1_context_create
    note: referenced by main.zig:15
    note:               /home/fiatjaf/.cache/zig/o/53d7067ceb3c7b7714a3622f5a802012/main.o:(main.main)
error: ld.lld: undefined symbol: secp256k1_ec_pubkey_create
    note: referenced by main.zig:16
    note:               /home/fiatjaf/.cache/zig/o/53d7067ceb3c7b7714a3622f5a802012/main.o:(main.main)
error: ld.lld: undefined symbol: secp256k1_ec_pubkey_serialize
    note: referenced by main.zig:23
    note:               /home/fiatjaf/.cache/zig/o/53d7067ceb3c7b7714a3622f5a802012/main.o:(main.main)
```

But yes, that would be a very hacky way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can't call `zig run` on files that have dependencies like that, you need to set up a `build.zig` and call `zig build`.

Here's an example `build.zig` that builds your `main.zig` file and declares the C dependencies:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn build(b: *std.Build) void {
    const exe = b.addExecutable(.{
        .name = "misc",
        .root_source_file = .{ .path = "main.zig" },
    });
    b.installArtifact(exe);

    exe.linkSystemLibrary("c");
    exe.linkSystemLibrary("secp256k1");
}
```

Then you just call

```
zig build
```

And your executable binary will be at `./zig-out/bin/misc`:

```bash
~> ./zig-out/bin/misc
public key (33): 026a04ab98d9e4774ad806e302dddeb63bea16b5cb5f223ee77478e861bb583eb3
```

[This article](https://zig.news/xq/zig-build-explained-part-2-1850) has more information on other things you can do inside `build.zig` with regards to C libraries (like statically linking them, compiling them together, vendoring them and so on).